# When cell value changes then run macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get this macro to action when Sheet = Settings and Cell = B3 value changes.

```
Sub TheSub()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

  Set copySheet = Worksheets("Country")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("9amCopy")

  copySheet.Range("B5:P28").Copy
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: In a comment to an Answer you said _as the cell change is coming from a data feed it doesn't work_.  That is critical information,  and should be added to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Calculate

- The following has to be copied to three different modules.

**ThisWorkbook module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    CurrentSettingsValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("B3").Value
End Sub
```

**Sheet module of worksheet "Settings" e.g. Sheet1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("B3").Value <> CurrentSettingsValue Then
        CopyRange
        CurrentSettingsValue = Range("B3").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. Module1**

```
Option Explicit

Public CurrentSettingsValue As Variant

Sub CopyRange()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    Dim src As Range
    Dim dst As Range
    
    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Country").Range("B5:P28")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("9amCopy")
        Set dst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    dst.Resize(src.Rows.Count, src.Columns.Count).Value = src.Value
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your sub is working fine. So, to run run the sub when value of `B3` cell changes use `Worksheet_Change()` event. Try below codes to call your sub when value `B3` changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
        Call TheSub
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still isn't working. Don't I need to tell it which sheet B3 is on? How do I go about telling it to activate macro only when Sheet = Settings and cell = B3 changes?

Comment: What do you mean by settings?

Comment: I've found the issue - if I type the change value in and press enter it works but as the cell change is coming from a data feed it doesn't work. Any way around this?

Comment: VBA will know which sheet B3 is on by the location of the event procedure. It must be in the code sheet of your worksheet `Settings`. The sub routine `TheSub` can be in a standard code module, such as `Module1`. However, if it isn't used anywhere else it would be better to place it in the same code module as the event procedure and declare it as `Private`. In fact, you may prefer to integrate its body in the event procedure itself where it would replace the line `Call TheSub`.

Comment: Thats @Variatus but now I have a new problem - if I type the change value in and press enter it works but as the cell change is coming from a data feed it doesn't work. Any way around this?

Comment: You should integrate `Call TheSub` into the update routine that changes B3.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` isn't triggered if the cell changes as the result of a formula calculation - only by manual editing (or e.g. a change performed from code).  Try the `Worksheet_Calculate` event